# Hit URL without opening browser in Retrofit Android

Tags: android, url, retrofit

I have seen some post **[like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42309314/4134215)**

But I need to do it using Retrofit. I have tested url in Postman. Body is empty and status is 200.

How can I execute(HIT) this without opening it in browser and empty response,

```
interface BackEndService {

    @GET
    suspend fun hitUrl(@Url url:String):Call<ResponseBody>
}
```

I have tried with Nothing , Any etc as response . But it isn't working

Can someone guide me how to achieve this

Comment: What is the url? Is it API or website? (if api why keep using word hit?)

Comment: Test it with any url like https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: They don't return empty body as you stated in your question. What is your problem exactly? Is it handling empty response body?

Comment: @Jemshit I want to know the return type to use for api call